# Оператор преобразования типа

Tags: операторы, c++

Какие аргументы и код возврата имеет оператор преобразования типа? В каких случаях неизбежно его использование?

Comment: что значит "код возврата"?

Comment: Код возврата - возвращаемое значение, если рассматривать этот оператор как функцию.

Comment: @gecube я вообще-то имел в виду, что обычно выражение "код возврата" имеет несколько более узкий смысл, нежели просто "возврщаемое значение", и если речь идет об операторах приведения, то употреблять его в этом контексте вряд ли правильно

Comment: @DreamChild, соглашусь, но в данном контексте не вижу другой возможной трактовки.

Comment: «В каких случаях неизбежно его использование?» звучит как вопрос из билетов на экзамен. А вообще, вопрос вне контекста конкретного языка не имеет смысла.

Comment: Если на экзаменах спрашивают про "коды возврата" операторов приведения, то ну их на хрен такие экзамены

Comment: Ага, звучит как вопрос из теста или экзамена..

Answer (score 3):

> Какие аргументы и код возврата имеет оператор преобразования типа?

1. аргумент один - приводимое значение.
2. оператор возвращает приведенное значение, причем, насколько я понимаю, это будет rvalue.

> В каких случаях неизбежно его использование?

1. в случае, когда компилятор не может "втихую" произвести преобразования типов. Для встроенных типов есть правила, которые определяют как типы могут преобразовываться. Например, `char` без проблем может быть преобразован в `int` и поэтому в ф-цию `void f(int x)` можно передать значение так: `f('a');`. При этом если существует версия ф-ции `void f(char x)`, то компилятор должен будет выбрать именно ее.
2. в случае, когда компилятор не может выбрать какую из перегруженных версий ф-ций нужно выбрать. Тогда программист выбирает конкретный вариант. Беря пример из первого случая, когда мы хотим значение `'a'` оттрактовать именно как целое, то нам придется использовать оператор преобразования типа: `f(static_cast<int>('a'))`.

Хочу обратить внимание, что хотя C++ и позволяет пользоваться приведением типа как в С (напр., `double x = 10; int a = (int)x;`), но лучше им не пользоваться, а пользоваться соответствующими операторами преобразования типа С++. Среди них есть и весьма интересные операторы (`const_cast`, `dynamic_cast`), работающие исключительно с указателями на классы и позволяющие, например, снять константность с указателя (может быть опасно, но нужно) и приводящие друг к другу базовые и производные классы. Второе может быть нужно для реализации полиморфизма на практике - работает с указателем на базовый класс, хотя на самом деле за ним скрывается объект производного класса.

Хорошую статью, а не мои путаные объяснения :-), про приведения типов можно посмотреть на ресурсе [Алёна CPP](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/08/c.html)

Comment: А вот ссылки на скучную, но полную документацию:

* [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast)
* [`static_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast)
* [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)
* [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)
* [C-style and functional cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

Answer (score 2):

Я хотел бы заострить внимание на разнице между приведением (cast) и преобразованием (conversion).

При преобразовании меняется машинное (битовое) представление переменой, а при приведении (cast) нет, меняются правила манипулирования этой переменной.

Пример преобразований

```
  int a = 100;
  printf ("int a = %d  sizeof(a): %ld   (double)a = %e  sizeof(double): %ld\n", 
      a, (long)sizeof(a), (double)a, (long)sizeof((double)a));
  printf ("sizeof(sizeof(a)) = %d\n", (int)sizeof(sizeof(a)));
```

результат

```
int a = 100  sizeof(a): 4   (double)a = 1.000000e+02  sizeof(double): 8
sizeof(sizeof(a)) = 8
```

Это пример с 64-бит машины. Преобразование в размере и битовом представлении между `int` и `double` очевидны.

Подробнее о `sizeof`. Тип оператора `sizeof` это `'long unsigned int'`, поэтому для *переносимости* между 32-бит (там `'long unsigned int'` занимает 4 байта) и 64-бит
в плане проверки компилятором формата в `printf` требуется явное преобразование типа.

В принципе, преобразование `(int)sizeof(...)` идет с усечением значения (старших разрядов), в данном случае это несущественно (т.к. числа маленькие). Но, правильным будет
использовать `"%ld"` в формате и `(long)sizeof` для переносимости при компиляции.

На практике приведение типа чаще всего необходимо при работе с указателями.

Например, если есть переменная типа int, а мы хотим посмотреть на "текст в ней", то без cast-а не обойтись. Или наоборот:

```
  const char *p = "cast";
  int *ip = (int *)p;
  printf ("%s = %d\n", (char *)ip, *ip);

  int b = 1414742339;
  printf ("А это десятичное число %d = ", b);
  for (p = (const char *)&b; (int *)p < &b + 1; p++)
    putchar(*p);

  long long bye = 0xa216579420a; 
  // long long для переносимости с 32-bit
  // нам тут нужно 5 байт для string terminated 0
  puts((char *)&bye);
```

результат

```
cast = 1953718627
А это десятичное число 1414742339 = CAST
Bye!
```